# Чи є український відповідник до слова “попкорн”?

Tags: синоніми

Вже з’явилося багато слів іншомовного походження, до яких подають питомі відповідники, зокрема: парасоля — розчепірка, суфікс — наросток, аеропорт — летовище та ін. Інформації щодо відповідника до слова попкорн не знайшла ні в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/popkorn), ні в інших словниках. Хіба є у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD) - баранці, бахканці, повітряна кукурудза, однак це не академічний словник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/popkorn)  знаходимо багато чудових українських відповідників:

> **Баранці, бахканці**, гопкуруза,кукурудзянці, кокоші, пуккукурудза, кукурудзяні баранці, кукурудзка, покукурудза, кукуракі, кукурудзяники, укрмаіс, кукурудзівка, бухканці, бубці, зернюхи, дзерно, кукурузка, пуканці, кукурудзики.

На іншому сайті [Вподобайка, лазівка та голярня: красиві українські слова, які замінять популярні запозичення](http://kozakorium.com/vpodobayka-lazivka-ta-holyarnya-krasyvi-ukrayinski-slova-yaki-zaminyat-populyarni-zapozychennya/):
**попкорн - баранці**

Однак, зважаючи на те, як Ви зазначали у попередньому запитанні, слово **попкорн** майже не фіксується у сучасних академічних виданнях словників. На жаль, науково-видавнича справа «не встигає» за розвитком мови, тому багато неологізмів і сучасних запозичень ще не ввійшли у словникові статті.

Отже, в багатьох неакадемічних джерелах повторюються одні й ті ж відповідники: **баранці,** *рідше* **бахканці**. Тому, на мою думку, вони мають величезний шанс ввійти у словникові статті як український відповідник **попкорну**.